# Javascript else if statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

### HTML

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="message">
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="send_message" placeholder="Enter text ...">  </textarea>
      <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">OK</a>
      <a href="#message" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">Cancel</a>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('#message').click(function(){
    if($("a", this).is(":contains(OK)")) {
        console.log("im in OK!!");
    } else if($("a", this).is(":contains(Cancel)"))  {
        console.log("im in cancel!!");
    }
});
```

This works fine when I hit the OK button and executes as expected, however when I hit cancel the code in OK is executed only. The cancel code never executes! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why should it execute if `a:contains('OK')` still exists in a `#message`?

Comment: It never enter the else if since $("a", this) contains both OK and Cancel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this` is the element the event is bound to.  It's *always* `#message`, therefore `$("a", this)` will always be the both buttons.  `.is` will scan both buttons to see if any of them contain `"OK"`.  The first one does, so it always goes to the 1st block.

You should be binding the events to the buttons themselves, not the entire div.

Comment: I'm (obviously) new to JS , but I figured it would be easiest to understand to bind the div and then select the children input elements. Are you saying that $("a", this) always picks the first 'a' that it comes across in the context of this?

Comment: @user61629: I'd suggest that as a beginner, you should bind to each button individually.  I was actually wrong.  `$("a", this)` picks *both*.  `.is` will scan everything in the set, so it always finds `OK`.

Answer (score 2):

Detect clicks on `a` from `#message`, instead. `this` will become the clicked `<a>`.

```
$('#message').on("click", "a", function(){
    if($(this).is(":contains(OK)")) {
        console.log("im in OK!!");
    } 
    else if($(this).is(":contains(Cancel)"))  {
            console.log("im in cancel!!");
    }
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aHvmt/)

Comment: Fixing the code isn't useful without explaining what was wrong with the original code.

Comment: @meagar You are correct. I always prefer to be faster and then to edit my answer adding more content.

Comment: @meagar Anyway the antispam stopped me to be first... :-)

Comment: @Johnツ why would you choose to provide an incomplete answer faster over just providing the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Fist, I noticed you have a missing closing div (`</div>`)

Just curious, why not do the following:

```
$("#OK").click (function() {
    console.log("im in OK!!");
});

$("#Cancel").click (function() {
    console.log("im in Cancel!!");
});

<div class="tab-pane" id="message">
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="send_message" placeholder="Enter text ...">  </textarea>
    <a href="#message" id="OK" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">OK</a>
    <a href="#message" id="Cancel" class="btn btn-large btn-info"  data-toggle="tab">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Cheers.